# Looking for graphical tool to compare 3 Git commits

Tags: git, gui

Consider this Git graph.

```
                      ----> [my-fork/develop]
                     /
[upstream/v2.0.0] --------> [upstream/v3.0.0]
```

I fork from a Git repo and make my own changes based on their version 2.0.0. In the meantime, the original repo evolves, resulting in version 3.0.0.

At this point, I consider re-integrating their changes into my repo. Before I do, I'd like to get a **graphical overview** of which files I changed and which files they changed, based on the common ancestor v2.0.0.

Here's what I'm looking for:

- A graphical tool where I can specify 3 Git commits (base, mine, theirs)
- Should run on Windows and OS X
- Similar to KDiff3, it lists the files modified only by me, only by them, and (most importantly) modified by both
- Similar to KDiff3, it can visualize a 3-way diff for these files

Here's what I *don't* want:

- A console tool that outputs formatted ANSI text on the console
- A merge tool that only displays conflicts
- A Git-agnostic tool (like KDiff3) that only works on directories

So far, all the graphical Git tools I found only support 2-way diffs between commits.

Comment: Out of curiosity; what keeps you from cloning the repository into three different directories, checking out a different branch in each, and using KDiff3 that way?

Comment: @Duroth: This is not a one-off task. I'm looking for a solution that my colleagues and I can use frequently. Sure, I could write a script to automate the steps you describe. But I'd much prefer a single tool that supports this feature out of the box.